# What type of lock is this? (image included)

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Yesterday, my wife was surfing the internet and caught this image with a "snipping tool".

So it looked like this:______[image: Doorlock]

After locking, it looked like this: [image: Doorlock]

Comment: That's a plain old, garden-variety door latch, I think sometimes called a "privacy latch" or something of that nature.  Used on bedroom and bathroom doors.  Some such latches use a twist knob, as shown, to lock/unlock access from the other side, others use a push button.

Comment: The style of knob in the pictures is a lever, but the same mechanism works with a conventional round knob -- it's all the same inside.  The lever style is most popular in modern US homes.

Comment: really? Where'd you get that data? According to Design Dilemma, the round knobs are more traditional.

Comment: @HotLicks: so the term is "twist knob"?

Comment: @sumelic - No, by "twist knob" I was referring to the little knob in the middle which can be twisted to change from "unlocked" to "locked".  The overall thing is, generically, a "latch" or a "doorknob".  "Privacy latch" is the specific type (lockable).  One that is not lockable is a "passage latch", I believe.

Comment: Can it be that this is a troll question? Look at the source of the image on the bottom right of it ("my wife surfing ... ?") and all the responses "knob", "door knob".

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Lever handle lock](https://www.google.it/search?q=lever%20handle%20door%20knob%20lock&biw=768&bih=909&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMI1KHQ_qjByAIVxD0UCh1HxAFX&dpr=2#imgrc=CpyUcycbMNmILM%3A)*** appears to be what it is called. A useful lock mainly used as indoor locks.